# R ggplot2 two categorical variables in facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I have a plot with aesthetic mappings `(gear, hp, col = cyl) + geom_line` and `geom_point`

```
data(mtcars)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(gear), hp, col = as.factor(cyl))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(cyl))) +
    facet_grid(cyl~.) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "goldenrod"))
```

This works just fine. The problem arises when I want to manually label the legend (guide)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(as.factor(gear), hp, col = as.factor(cyl))) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(cyl))) +
    facet_grid(cyl~.) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "goldenrod"), name = "Cylinder)
```

It pulls apart the legend and splits it into two: Cylinder (with cols) and `as.factor(cyl)` for the shapes. How do I get rid of the `as.factor(cyl)` or keep the legend combined and still rename it manually? I assume I just need to shift some things around.

Comment: Add `scale_shape_discrete(name="Cylinder")`. You require two mappings that get default names and labels. When you change the name or labels of one, the other keeps its default and is drawn separately.

Comment: That did it!!! Awesome! Thanks for the quick answer @PierreLafortune